# A person messages on a Discord server and leaves. Would a reply to their message notify them?

Tags: notifications, discord

Alice joins a Discord server and leaves some messages. Then she leaves. Would a reply to her messages notify her?

The [Replies FAQ – Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360057382374-Replies-FAQ) doesn't say anything about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because she isn't in the server anymore. That server doesn't appear anymore in her list of servers. So there is no way for her to get a notification from a server that isn't even in her list of servers.

Comment: what if she rejoins it back? Would the pings in the server notify her as if she has never left?